# Timing in javascript sequencer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, web-applications, html5-audio

I have developed a music sequencer in javascript; something like this: http://stepseq.michd.me/
I have implemented loop using setInterval function in following way:

```
var Sequencer = {
...
// every step sequencer ...
next: function(callback) {
        // restart from begin if arrive to last sequecer step
        if(Sequencer.current==Sequencer.steps.length)
            Sequencer.current = 0;
        // play all sounds in array  step contains
        if(Sequencer.steps[Sequencer.current].length>0) {
            var set = Sequencer.steps[Sequencer.current];
            for(var i=0;i<set.length;i++){
                set[i].play();
            }
        }
        callback(Sequencer.current);
        Sequencer.current++;
    },

loop: function(callback) {
        Sequencer.interval = $interval(function(){
            Sequencer.next(callback);
        }, Sequencer.time);
    }
}
...
```

Code below works but i think that there is a better way to implement loop; infact sometimes steps goes out of time. Sequencer.time (time passed to setInterval function) is a time in millisecs (this value is the conversion of a bpm value; for example it can be 125),

Someone can suggest me a better solution?

**N.B.: this is a web application angularjs based (for this reason in code above a use $interval insteed of setInterval), but i think that this point is insignificant.**

Comment: [This gist](https://gist.github.com/manast/1185904) may be relevant to your interests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript timer intervals are not guaranteed to run at exactly the time you request, due to the single threaded nature of JS.  What you get is a callback that is queued up to run after the interval expires, **whenever the engine is free to run it**.

John resig has covered this off in some depth:

http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

http://ejohn.org/blog/analyzing-timer-performance/

And from his conclusions, which is going to be important for your app:

> If a timer is blocked from immediately executing it will be delayed
>   until the next possible point of execution (which will be longer than
>   the desired delay).

I don't really have a better solution for your problem, due to these fundamental issues with timers in JS, but this may at least explain what is happening.